# Javascript - need to get a value from an HTML table ROW/CELL and then check true or false in script

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-core, razor

I have a simple table.  When a user clicks on a row, a jscript gets triggered.  How can I get a value from row/cell to use in jscript to check true or false please?  There is also a seperate click-row script but ignore that for now.

```
<tbody>
@if (Model != null)
{
  foreach (CELIntranet.Models.tblReportsList item in Model)
  {
  <tr class="clickable-row" id="myid" data-mydata1=UserPermission href="@Url.Action("ShowReport", new { ReportViewName = item.ReportViewName,
                                   ReportController = item.ReportController, UserPermission = (User.IsInRole(item.ReportUserRoles) || User.IsInRole("Administrator")) })">
      <td>@Html.Raw(item.ReportNumber)</td>
      <td>@Html.Raw(item.ReportName)</td>
      <td>@Html.Raw(item.ReportGroup)</td>
      <td>@Html.Raw(item.ReportStatus)</td>

    @if (User.IsInRole(item.ReportUserRoles) || User.IsInRole("Administrator"))
    {
      <td style="color:dodgerblue">Granted</td>
    }
    else
    {
      <td style="color:orangered">Restricted</td>
    }
  </tr>
  }
}
</tbody>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {

        var ClickedTableRowCellValue = ("Need some code to get UserPermission value from the clicked row");

        $('table > tbody > tr').click(function () {

            if (ClickedTableRowCellValue == True) {
                alert("Granted");
                Popup();
            }
            alert("Restricted");
        });
    });

</script>




// Click row ignore this code for now!

@section Scripts {

<script type="text/javascript">

    var clicker = new TableCliker();

    $(document).ready(function () {
    clicker.Initialise();
    //alert("Test");
    //Popup();
    });

</script>
```

Comment: is the `$` in your code an alias for `jquery`?

Comment: It might be handy to tag this with whatever framework it is that you are using as that markup is not instantly familiar to some

Comment: Are you using ASP.Net?

Comment: Sorry, novice coder here.  The code is for ASP.NET MVC project.

Comment: It looks like the `href` attribute you create for each `<tr>` contains a value that depends on the access privileges of the user. So, a logical way would be to look at the actual values of this attribute and decide whether that is to be treated as "true" or "false".

Comment: true or false is from UserPermission = (User.IsInRole(item.ReportUserRoles) || User.IsInRole("Administrator")) })"> from <tr

Comment: Down vote as the question (and the selected answer) are unhelpful to others.  This is not the correct way to handle events and model changes on an MVC Razor page.

Comment: It looks like UserPermission is inside the href,you need to put it outside href.

Comment: Hi,is my answer helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change your html like this:

```
<tr class="clickable-row" id="myid" onclick="test(this)" UserPermission = "@(User.IsInRole(item.ReportUserRoles) || User.IsInRole("Administrator"))" data-mydata1=UserPermission href="@Url.Action("ShowReport", new { ReportViewName = item.ReportViewName,
                                   ReportController = item.ReportController, UserPermission = (User.IsInRole(item.ReportUserRoles) || User.IsInRole("Administrator")) })">
```

So that you can add UserPermission attribute to `<tr></tr>`.Here is the js:

```
function test(t){
     var ClickedTableRowCellValue = $(t).attr("UserPermission").
     if (ClickedTableRowCellValue == True) {
                alert("Granted");
                Popup();
            }
            alert("Restricted");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the `click()` event returns the exact element that was clicked you can simply use `this` (the element that is clicked). And get the attribute `UserPermission`.

```
$('tr').click(function () {
    var authorized = $(this).attr("UserPermission");
    
    if (authorized) { // you don't need to state == true since it will compare to true by default
        alert("Granted");
        Popup();
    }

    alert("Restricted");
});
```

Comment: Awsome, thank you rbdeenk.

Comment: just as an FYI (people have already told you) but make sure to clarify exactly what tech stack you are using. I work with the exact tech stack and even i wasn't completely sure. I would also recommend typing out jscript as javascript since JScript is a language made by microsoft.

Comment: I thought this was working.  I think you are on the right track but when I tested it, authorized is returned as undefined?

Comment: Could you make sure that `UserPermission` is not `userPermission`. Make sure in the html in the website that UserPermission exists or in other cases see what else contains this value